# "expected struct String, found struct schema::my_table::columns::my_column" when trying to insert value with Diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to execute an insert multiple columns using [Diesel](http://diesel.rs) with PostgreSQL.

This is the insert function to add a new `Project` -

```
pub fn insert(project: NewProject, program_id: i32, conn: &PgConnection) -> bool {
    use schema::projects::dsl::*;
    use schema::projects::dsl::{title as t};
    use schema::projects::dsl::{program_id as prog_id};

    let NewProject {
        title
    } = project;

    diesel::insert_into(projects)
        .values((t.eq(title), prog_id.eq(program_id)))
        .execute(conn)
        .is_ok()
}
```

And `Project` and `NewProject`

```
#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Project {
    pub id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub program_id: i32,
    pub is_archived: bool
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "projects"]
pub struct NewProject {
    pub title: String
}
```

And the projects table looks like this -

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    program_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES programs (id),
    is_archived BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

and the schema.rs -

```
table! {
projects (id) {
    id -> Int4,
    title -> Varchar,
    program_id -> Int4,
    is_archived -> Bool,
}
```

When compiled I get an error saying -

> title    |             ^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`,
>   found struct `schema::projects::columns::title`

and

> .execute(conn)    |              ^^^^^^^ expected struct
>   `diesel::query_source::Never`, found struct
>   `diesel::query_source::Once`

I do not get a compile error when I do

```
.values(&project)
```

in the insert function instead.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. For example, you haven't provided your `table!` macro calls (not complete) and we don't need to know anything about Rocket (not minimal). Try to produce something that reproduces your error in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well as [Diesel-specific tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) to make small examples.

Comment: Apologize for not adhering to the MCVE. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why is `Project` relevant? Where is it used? Again: **minimal**.

Comment: Why are `Serialize` and `Deserialize` provided? Are they required to reproduce the problem? *minimal*.

Comment: What version of Diesel? Are you using any Cargo features for Diesel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;

mod schema {
    table! {
        projects (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            title -> Varchar,
            program_id -> Int4,
            is_archived -> Bool,
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
    #[table_name = "projects"]
    pub struct NewProject {
        pub title: String,
    }
}

use schema::NewProject;

fn insert(project: NewProject, program_id: i32, conn: &PgConnection) -> bool {
    use schema::projects::dsl::*;
    use schema::projects::dsl::{title as t};
    use schema::projects::dsl::{program_id as prog_id};

    let NewProject {
        title
    } = project;

    diesel::insert_into(projects)
        .values((t.eq(title), prog_id.eq(program_id)))
        .execute(conn)
        .is_ok()
}

fn main() {}
```

You have imported a type called `title` that conflicts with the destructuring, as the error message states:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:34:22
   |
34 |     let NewProject { title } = project;
   |                      ^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found struct `schema::projects::columns::title`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `schema::projects::columns::title`
```

This can be reduced to a very small case:

```
struct foo;
struct Thing { foo: String }

fn example(t: Thing) {
    let Thing { foo } = t;
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:17
  |
5 |     let Thing { foo } = t;
  |                 ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found struct `foo`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `foo`
```

Note that this struct is defined without curly braces, which makes it a *unit-like struct*. These are convenient, but they have the subtle nuance that they create both a *type* and a *value*:

```
struct foo;

fn example() {
    let foo: foo = foo;
    //             ^-- the only value of the type `foo`
    //       ^-------- the type `foo`
    //  ^------------- newly-defined unrelated identifier
}
```

When destructuring, the pattern is preferred as a *type*, not an identifier.

Don't import that type and you won't have a conflict:

```
fn insert(project: NewProject, program_id: i32, conn: &PgConnection) -> bool {
    use schema::projects::dsl;

    let NewProject { title } = project;

    diesel::insert_into(dsl::projects)
        .values((dsl::title.eq(title), dsl::program_id.eq(program_id)))
        .execute(conn)
        .is_ok()
}
```